# BeautifulSoup can't get links from a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get user links from a table, but I'm failing

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    html_users = requests.get('http://teamfinding.com/ru/search/team/lucky')
    soup_users = BeautifulSoup(html_users.content, 'html.parser')
    res = soup_users.find('table', class_='table table-bordered table-striped')
    print(res)

results: []
>>>
```

What i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm just not logged in before **scraping**. But i'm usually logging via google accounts, so now it is a much bigger problem